# Explain Auto-Encoders to me please

Tags: autoencoder

What I've read says that the output is the input, and that if you have an error trying to reconstruct an observation then it is anomalous. That makes sense to me. The problem I'm having is this:

I'm familiar with supervised methods, so here's what I'm thinking. Normally when you make a model you have an observation, usually with many features, that lead to an outcome. You learn how these features relate to produce the outcome.

For an auto-encoder, is it true that each observation uses n-1 features to predict the remaining feature? The model is created assuming some hidden structure and then it attempts to reconstruct it like that?

Just a little confused, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What I've read says that the output is the input

Strictly speaking, we want the output to be as "**close**" as the input. In machine learning, we have a loss function (e.g., cross entropy, L2-norm), the "closer" of the output to the input, the less loss it will be. But the **dimensions** of input and output are the **same**.

> if you have an error trying to reconstruct an observation then it is anomalous

In the autoencoders, the number of neurons of hidden layer is **smaller** than the number of neurons of input layer. In light of this, part of information is lost during reconstruction.

> For an auto-encoder, is it true that each observation uses n-1 features

What is n? You can choose arbitrary number of neurons for hidden layer as long as the number is smaller than that of input.